# Getting `state not defined` error when it is defined

Tags: angularjs

In my angular application I want to go to another page on a click of a button. For that I use GoNext function. Below is my code that gives me `state is not defined` error. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

```
(function () {
    angular.module("MyApp").controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "$state", "$http", MainCtrlFunction]);
    function MainCtrlFunction($scope, $state, $http) {

    ....



        $scope.GoNext = function () {
            state.go("screen2");
        }


    }

})();
```

I do have a corresponding entry in my config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've miss typed the service `$state`'s name. It's just a confusion because you have two things named `state` on your code: the argument `$state` which is a service and the state of your aplication router; Anyways, it should look like:

```
$state.go("screen2");
```

Instead of:

```
state.go("screen2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use $state and make sure it's injected into your controller.  Seems you used state w no dollar symbol.